# Unit Tests timeout when run together, succeed when run individually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I've been searching around and haven't seen anyone noting this particular issue, basically I'm writing some fairly basic unit tests to assess a web API for a university module and where the tests all succeed or fail in the way they are supposed to, running them using the 'Run All' option causes them all to timeout.

Any tips would be really helpful.

Comment: Do any tests pass when you run all? Look for static objects. Find a minimal subset that exhibits the behaviour and investigate.

Comment: None of them pass, they all timeout. There are no static objects in use, as I say, all I'm doing is testing the server's responses to specific requests.

Comment: "Testing the server responses to specific requests" does not sound like a unit test.

Unit testing is where you test your code, not send requests to a server.

Are you sure your server is setup correctly and there is no race condition there? Are you sure there is nothing static about your tests? Are you sure you are not trying to setup multiple servers for the same IP or port, and one stomps on another before you manage to hit it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on what you have said, the most likely explanation is that you are not doing `Run` in the first scenario, you are doing `Debug`. When you debug Visual Studio automatically hosts your website for you; meaning that your test code connects to the automatically hosted website. When you do `Run All` there is no site there to debug so it just times out.

As Yishai points out you are not unit testing: unit testing at the very least would only test code on one side of the service boundary - by definition if you need to have a web server running for your tests to pass then they are not unit tests, they are integration tests.